# make array from a list of images with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, image, arrays

i have a list of photos like this:

```
<div class="upimage">
    <ul id="upimagesQueue" class="thumbs ui-sortable">
    <li id="upimagesKHGYUD">
        <a href="uploads/0002.jpg">
            <img src="uploads/0002.jpg" id="KHGYUD">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="upimagesNCEEKI">
        <a href="uploads/0003.jpg">
            <img src="uploads/0003.jpg" id="NCEEKI">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="upimagesPWSHUN">
        <a href="uploads/0003.jpg">
            <img src="uploads/0003.jpg" id="PWSHUN">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="upimagesOYJAQV">
        <a href="uploads/0004.jpg">
            <img src="uploads/0004.jpg" id="OYJAQV">
        </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i want to make a function in jquery  too get all the images in 1 array to be able to sent the array to php! the array i want to be in this form:

```
array(
    'image_id_1' => array(
        'image_src_1' => 'xyz.jpg',
    )
    'image_id_2' => array(
        'image_src_2' => 'xyz.jpg',
    )
    'image_id_3' => array(
        'image_src_3' => 'xyz.jpg',
    )
    'image_id_4' => array(
        'image_src_4' => 'xyz.jpg',
    )
)
```

how i can code this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

**DEMO:** hhttp://jsbin.com/idovi3/6

from what you asked the jQUERY PLUGIN is ;-)

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.serializeImages = function() {
       //create the array...
       var toReturn    = [];
       //get the LI
       var els = $(this);
       //loop trought each LI ...
        $.each(els, function(i) {
         //get the Li id...
        var id = $(this).children().children().attr('id');
         //get the img src of the parent A parent IMG...
        var val = $(this).children().children().attr('src').split('uploads/')[1];
         //put each item in the array...
        toReturn.push( 
         // format the array...         
        id + ' => array( "image_src_' + i + '"' + ' => ' + val  + ', )'

            );           
        });   
        //join all into one single var for easy access.. 
        // \n can be whatever you want      
        var array =  toReturn.join('\n');

        return array; 
    }

})(jQuery);

  $(function () {
    var serie = $('ul li').serializeImages();
    alert(serie); 
  });
```

**ECHO:**

```
KHGYUD => array( "image_src_0" => 0002.jpg, )
NCEEKI => array( "image_src_1" => 0003.jpg, )
PWSHUN => array( "image_src_2" => 0003.jpg, )
OYJAQV => array( "image_src_3" => 0004.jpg, )
```

Comment: nice! but how i can recive the id to? i add "var id = $(this).attr('id');" but not working

Comment: i added "var id = $(this).children().children().attr('id');" to get the image id!

Answer (score 5):

```
var a = {};
$(".upimage img").each(function() {
  a[this.id] = $(this).attr("src");
});
```

would give you

```
a = {
  "KHGYUD": "uploads/0002.jpg",
  "NCEEKI": "uploads/0003.jpg",
  "PWSHUN": "uploads/0003.jpg",
  "OYJAQV": "uploads/0004.jpg"
};
```

Not sure why you would want a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: as upimage is div's class it should be $(".upimage img")... or $("#upimagesQueue img")...

Comment: i will need to add more data , thats why i need multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @robertdd: Please make a more useful output sample. Yours does not even reflect your input. Also don't forget to include a case where the nested array actually makes sense.

Comment: @robertdd: Being responsive is actually a good thing. You should try it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = {};
$('.upimage li').each(function(){
  var $img   = $(this).find('img'),
      imgObj = {};

  imgObj[$img.attr('src')] = $img.attr('id');
  images[$(this).attr('id')] = imgObj;
});

// Then to send to php
$.post('url', images, function(){ /* success */ });
```

(it seems like you had the image src in their twice, so I just assumed you meant the li id first then the image src, either way, it's a small change)